# NSJSONSerialization with small decimal numbers

Tags: json, swift

I'm attemptin to include the `Double` value of `0.81` in some JSON generated by `NSJSONSerialization`. The code is as follows:

```
let jsonInput = [ "value": 0.81 ]
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonInput, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print( json )
```

The output is:

```
{
  "value" : 0.8100000000000001
}
```

But what I'd like to see is:

```
{
  "value" : 0.81
}
```

**How can I make `NSJSONSerialization` do this?**

One further thing that is confusing me here is Swift's handling of the 64bit `Double`. As in the playground I can also do this:

```
let eightOne:Double = 0.81
"\(eightOne)"
print( eightOne )
```

And the output is then as desired with:

```
0.81
```

Even though in the playground it shows `eightOne` as `0.8100000000000001` as far as internal representation goes. However here when it converts to string it chops off the rest.

I'm surely this is solved, as you'd need it sorted for any kind of financial handling (eg. in Java we know we only use `BigDecimals` when it comes to financial values).

Please help. :)

**NOTE:** The focus here is on serialization to JSON. Not just a simple call off to `NSString( format: "%\(0.2)f", 0.81)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For precise base-10 arithmetic (up to 38 significant digits)
you can use `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
let jsonInput = [ "value":  NSDecimalNumber(string: "0.81") ]
```

or

```
let val = NSDecimalNumber(integer: 81).decimalNumberByDividingBy(NSDecimalNumber(integer: 100))
let jsonInput = [ "value":  val ]
```

Then

```
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonInput, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
print( json )
```

produces the output

```
{
  "value" : 0.81
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Manual conversion

You'll need to convert your `Double` to a `Decimal` to keep its expected string representation when serializing.

One way to avoid a precision of 16 digits may be to round with a scale of 15:

```
(0.81 as NSDecimalNumber).rounding(accordingToBehavior: NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 15, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: true, raiseOnUnderflow: true, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)) as Decimal
```

#### JSONSerialization extension for automatic conversion

To automatically and recursively do it for all `Double` values in your JSON object, being it a Dictionary or an Array, you can use:

```
import Foundation

/// https://stackoverflow.com/q/35053577/1033581
extension JSONSerialization {

    /// Produce Double values as Decimal values.
    open class func decimalData(withJSONObject obj: Any, options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []) throws -> Data {
        return try data(withJSONObject: decimalObject(obj), options: opt)
    }

    /// Write Double values as Decimal values.
    open class func writeDecimalJSONObject(_ obj: Any, to stream: OutputStream, options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = [], error: NSErrorPointer) -> Int {
        return writeJSONObject(decimalObject(obj), to: stream, options: opt, error: error)
    }

    fileprivate static let roundingBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 15, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: true, raiseOnUnderflow: true, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)

    fileprivate static func decimalObject(_ anObject: Any) -> Any {
        let value: Any
        if let n = anObject as? [String: Any] {
            // subclassing children
            let dic = DecimalDictionary()
            n.forEach { dic.setObject($1, forKey: $0) }
            value = dic
        } else if let n = anObject as? [Any] {
            // subclassing children
            let arr = DecimalArray()
            n.forEach { arr.add($0) }
            value = arr
        } else if let n = anObject as? NSNumber, CFNumberGetType(n) == .float64Type {
            // converting precision for correct decimal output
            value = NSDecimalNumber(value: anObject as! Double).rounding(accordingToBehavior: roundingBehavior)
        } else {
            value = anObject
        }
        return value
    }
}

private class DecimalDictionary: NSDictionary {
    let _dictionary: NSMutableDictionary = [:]

    override var count: Int {
        return _dictionary.count
    }
    override func keyEnumerator() -> NSEnumerator {
        return _dictionary.keyEnumerator()
    }
    override func object(forKey aKey: Any) -> Any? {
        return _dictionary.object(forKey: aKey)
    }

    func setObject(_ anObject: Any, forKey aKey: String) {
        let value = JSONSerialization.decimalObject(anObject)
        _dictionary.setObject(value, forKey: aKey as NSString)
    }
}

private class DecimalArray: NSArray {
    let _array: NSMutableArray = []

    override var count: Int {
        return _array.count
    }
    override func object(at index: Int) -> Any {
        return _array.object(at: index)
    }

    func add(_ anObject: Any) {
        let value = JSONSerialization.decimalObject(anObject)
        _array.add(value)
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
JSONSerialization.decimalData(withJSONObject: [ "value": 0.81 ], options: [])
```

#### Note

If you need fine tuning of decimal formatting, you can check Eneko Alonso answer on [Specify number of decimals when serializing currencies with JSONSerialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420375/specify-number-of-decimals-when-serializing-currencies-with-jsonserialization).

Comment: "((0.81 as NSNumber).decimalValue)" returns "0.8100000000000001" Xcode 11.3.1

Comment: @AntonPlebanovich oh, something may have changed in 2 years. Well, I've edited the message with a different workaround.

Comment: It looks like we need to use `scale: 13`. Otherwise for `32.98` with rounding `15` it produces `32.979999999999995` and `32.97999999999999` with rounding `14`

Comment: It looks like we need to use a dynamic rounding scale that depends on the integral part size actually. For `123123123.123213` it produces `123123123.1232130048`

Answer (score 0):

If you have use 'NSDecimalNumber' demand, it is suggested that encapsulate for ease of use and reduce mistakes.

Here's the Demo for you reference, using a simple.The hope can help you!

```
switch (operatorType) {
  case 0:
      resultNumber = SNAdd(_cardinalNumberTextField.text, _complementNumberTextField.text);
      break;
  case 1:
      resultNumber = SNSub(_cardinalNumberTextField.text, _complementNumberTextField.text);
      break;
  case 2:
      resultNumber = SNMul(_cardinalNumberTextField.text, _complementNumberTextField.text);
      break;
  case 3:
      resultNumber = SNDiv(_cardinalNumberTextField.text, _complementNumberTextField.text);
      break;
 }
```

Github:https://github.com/ReverseScale/DecimalNumberDemo